# Set class to an input with twig

Tags: 8, theming

Hello i am working on theming for Drupal 8 using twig 
My question is :
I want to assign css class to each input swicth the type of the input
exemple
 `<input type='email' class='email_cls'>`

```
<input type='submit' class='submit_cls'>
```

what code should i use ,knowing that i use the default template twig file **input.html.twig** 
 I did this

```
<input{{ attributes.addClass('submit_cls email_cls') }} />{{ children }}
```

The problem is on my form both of the inputs email & submit have the same display

Answer (score 3):

You could use this in your theme:

```
function template_preprocess_input(&$variables) {
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'your_class';
}
```

and maybe even check the type like:

```
function template_preprocess_input(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['attributes']['type'] == 'email') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'your_class_email';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable suggestion templates by adding in your settings.php (in /site/_your_website_)

```
$settings['theme_debug'] = true;"
```

and you will see in your DOM inspector some suggestions in HTML comments like "input--file.html.twig" for input of type file.